# Printer redirection on server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, printing

On windows server 2003 when one user connects to the server via RDP the default printer of the server for her profile does not change to the redirected printer of the session. 
This only happens with the one user all the other users default printers defaults to their session printer automatically.
I tried the following solution but there was no \Terminal Server\Printer Redirection in gpedit.msc
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731963(v=ws.10).aspx

> Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Terminal Services\Terminal Server\Printer Redirection

Is there a different place to check the Printer Redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.

> Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Terminal Services\Client/server data redirection\Do not set default printer to be default printer in a session

Change this to NO and now it works. =D

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried modeling the user in gpmc?

- Start → Run → gpmc.msc (you must install it first)
- Right-click Group Policy Modeling → Group Policy Modeling Wizard
- Next → Next → Click User, browse for the user name → Click Computer, browse for the computer name → Next → Next → Next → Next → Next → Next → Finish

Name the query, after the report generates, click the settings tab and review your settings.